# how do i load 2 different pages depending on the time?

Tags: php

I have two different index pages.

I need to load one between 6:00-18:00 hrs and the second at 18:00-6:00 hrs.

How would I do this with php?

Comment: What about between 00:00 and 06:00?

Comment: In Singapore, this is called midnight charges for taxi

Comment: I don't understand that's "not real" about this question. I don't think closing this is appropriate at all.

Comment: Must this be handled with PHP?  A cron job could just swap your index pages at the appropriate times.

Comment: @EFraim in some sense yes, there is a question here, but the OP has put no real effort elaborating properly what he wants.

Comment: What about he index redirecting_to/including the right page at the right time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php
    $hour = localtime(time(), true)["tm_hour"];

    if ($hour >= 6 && $hour < 18) {
        include "daytime.php";
    } else {
        include "nighttime.php";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `localtime()` is not an associative array by default you need `localtime(time(),true)` instead

Comment: Thanks ManseUK. Missed that part! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?
$hour = (int)date("H");
if($hour >= 6 && $hour < 18)
    include "index1.php";
else
    include "index2.php";
?>
```

Also [PHP date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is useful for your needs

**Update:** Added cast to int

Comment: I wouldn't use `date()`, because it returns string. I know that php will convert string to number at the point of comparison, but it still has some bad code smell. If I were to use `date()`, I'd compare with string literals '06' and '18' instead.